# Modify the data returned by a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

i am current using this plugin for tags-input 'bootstrap-tagsinput'

i am trying to use the typeahead feature provided by this plugin.
the source attribute in typeahead expects a promise to be returned.but i need to modify the returned data. How do i do this?

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {                  
    source: function(query) {
      return $.get('/tags.json').then(function(data){
          return _.pluck(data.tags,'keyword');
       });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you create your own Deferred object and resolve it after you get the data from the ajax and modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var list = ["Amsterdam", "Beijing", "Cairo"];
var citynames = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: '/tags.json',
        filter: function (res) {
            // modify returned data here ,
            // e.g., `res` : `["abc"]`
            return $.map(res[0].split(""), function (val, i) {
                return {
                    name: val.toUpperCase() === list[i][0] ? list[i] : null
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
citynames.initialize();

$('input.bootstrap-tagsinput').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'citynames',
        displayKey: 'name',
        valueKey: 'name',
        source: citynames.ttAdapter()
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/dbfx1tso/

See [Bootstrap Tags Input Typeahead](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#example_typeahead)